Flutter: How to change the text size of the dialog box
shThe problem is when changing the text size of the dialog box, it does not change, but if it is outside the dialog box, the text size changes without problems, which I only want when the user selects on the box, the text size changes immediately or automatically, and thank you
Picture dialog box with checkbox
٢
enter image description here
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.

        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
double textSize = 14;
bool _cesbox = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

             Text(
              'Flutter\n',style:TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),
            ),
          
              Text("Click on the box to enlarge the text\n"),
              Checkbox(

                value: _cesbox,
               onChanged: (newbool){

             setState(() {
                      _cesbox=newbool!;
                     if (_cesbox==true) {

                            textSize=40;

                           }

                             });
                                  }

                              ),

            IconButton(onPressed: (){
              showDialog(
                  context: context,

                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(

                      content: StatefulBuilder(
                        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [

                              Text("Click on the box to enlarge the text"),
                              Checkbox(

                                  value: _cesbox,
                                  onChanged: (newbool){

                                    setState(() {
                                      _cesbox=newbool!;
                                      if (_cesbox==true) {

                                        textSize=40;

                                      }

                                    });
                                  }

                              ),

                            ],
                          ) ;


                        },

                      ) ,

                    )  ;
                  }

              );

            }
                ,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu,size: 25,color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 50, 50),)),


          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}


I want to enlarge the word filter by entering the dialog box and resizing the text from there

You can do that in couple of ways.

Using setState().

IconButton(
  onPressed: () async { // add async here
    await showDialog( // await till dialog box closes.
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: StatefulBuilder(
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("Click on the box to enlarge the text"),
                    Checkbox(
                      value: _cesbox,
                      onChanged: (newbool) {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            _cesbox = newbool!;
                            if (_cesbox == true) {
                              textSize = 40;
                            }
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        });
    setState(() {}); // update widget.
  },
  icon: const Icon(
    Icons.menu,
    size: 25,
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 50, 50),
  ),
),


Using ValueNotifier


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ValueNotifier<double> textSizeNotifier = ValueNotifier(14);
  bool _cesbox = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ValueListenableBuilder<double>(
                valueListenable: textSizeNotifier,
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Flutter\n',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: value),
                      ),
                      Text("Click on the box to enlarge the text\n"),
                      Checkbox(
                          value: _cesbox,
                          onChanged: (newbool) {
                            setState(() {
                              _cesbox = newbool!;
                              if (_cesbox == true) {
                                textSizeNotifier.value = 40;
                              }
                            });
                          })
                    ],
                  );
                }),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: StatefulBuilder(
                          builder:
                              (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                Text("Click on the box to enlarge the text"),
                                Checkbox(
                                  value: _cesbox,
                                  onChanged: (newbool) {
                                    setState(
                                      () {
                                        _cesbox = newbool!;
                                        if (_cesbox == true) {
                                          textSizeNotifier.value = 40;
                                        }
                                      },
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                size: 25,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 50, 50),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Brother, thank you. I am very happy. I have been trying to read it for two days
But please can you explain what the problem is

When you show a dialog, it is displayed in a separate context from the main widget. The setState method called inside the dialog only affects the state of the dialog's widget tree, not the main widget tree. So either you need to wait till dialog closes or use notifier to update the main widget.
